# how to use special letters in bib file properly?

Tags: spacing, bibliographies

Some author's name contains special characters like "ł" in **Szałowski**. The latex code for "ł" is `\l`.

But if I write the name in bib file as `Sza\l owski`, the the name contained in the output pdf's reference will be "Szał owski". That is to say, there will be a space in the name.

But if I write `Sza\l owski` in the main text of latex file, then the name will be ok without space.

**So why there will be a space? How to deal special character in bib file?**

and a related question: In the main text of LaTeX file, no matter how many space after `\l`, the output is the same. That is to say, the output of `Sza\l owski` is the same as that of `Sza\l    owski`, both output "Szałowski". Then what should I do if I want "Szał owski" in the main text.

Comment: The question about forcing a space is separate from the main part, and has been asked many times. TeX skips spaces after macro names, so you need to force a space with `\l\ ` or stop the space skipping with `\l{} `.

Comment: @JosephWright I found use "{\l}" also works in the main text